# Can someone under the effect of Join Pasts lie?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e

Specifically looking at Pathfinder's [Join Pasts](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=552), which reads:

> With touches to the targets’ foreheads, you bring them into mental communion. The targets can share thoughts and experiences, but not words. When one target attempts to Recall Knowledge, the other can Aid the first target’s skill check, using any Lore skill (even if that Lore wouldn’t normally apply) without having made any preparations to Aid.

Could someone under the effect of this cantrip lie when sharing a thought or an experience? In my game, we've used this spell to look at a target's past experiences and see things through their eyes - but the idea that they could just lie (for instance, by sharing that they grew up impoverished or were stolen from) came up recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Probably

The effect you describe is outside of the described use for the spell, so there is no more guidance given about how that portion works beyond the quoted text. Interpretation is up to your GM.

> The targets can share thoughts and experiences, but not words.

Imagine yourself... laying on the beach, relaxing... having a good time. That's a thought. You could think of a time you were actually at the beach, or you could think of yourself in a commercial set on the beach and it would largely feel the same to you. Alternatively, you could describe one as an experience and know that they're different because you have actual sensory memory of one but not the other.

They could be running it either way. If it's going to affect your ability to enjoy the game, ask your GM for an honest out-of-character answer, and if you characters would know the answer.